# Python XML trying to store elements in variables

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to display elements from an XML file in tkinter Entry and Text widgets.

Example XML:

```
<notes>
   <note id="5/10/22/14:20">
      <index>5/10/22, 14:20 > Mr Anderson</index>
      <date>5/10/22</date>
      <time>14:20</time>
      <from>Agt Smith</from>
      <to>Mr Anderson</to>
      <subject>App Test 3</subject>
      <body>Do you hear that, Mr. Anderson? That is the sound of inevitability.</body>
   </note>
</notes>
```

I was going to try getchildren() but I am told that is deprecated. I want to use the note id to pull up that element and its children, and insert various children into the correlating Entry and Text widgets. However, I cannot seem to get the correct values into variables. It feels like it should be simple and easy, but my instincts are leading me astray. What I am getting from this code is all of the entries displaying, rather than one selected by the note id. This is my code:

```
def displayNote(self):
    # Clear the boxes first
    clearBoxes()
    
    # get index value
    for i in noteList.curselection():
        noteIndex = noteList.get(i)
        
    # process index value to get id
    subStrip = ' >.*'
    noteStrip = noteIndex.replace(", " , "/").replace(":" , "")
    noteID = re.sub(subStrip , "" , noteStrip)

    # parse xml for box display
    fileForDisplay = ET.parse(notefile)
    rootd = fileForDisplay.getroot()

    # and pull the info for that note id into variables
    for note in rootd.findall('note'):
        dateInfo = note.find("date").text
        toInfo = note.find("to").text
        fromInfo = note.find("from").text
        subjectInfo = note.find("subject").text
        bodyInfo = note.find("body").text
        timeInfo = note.find("time").text
        bodyDisplay = timeInfo + "\n" + bodyInfo
```

Comment: Just to be clear, you're not really asking about tkinter, but how to parse and step through the nodes of an XML document?

Comment: Correct -- tkinter itself is not the issue.

Comment: You might want to consider stripping out the tkinter code from your example so that more people might be willing to help.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: It is attempting to display every note node, not the intended one.